# Error in the start.php file after hosting the laravel 4 as sub-domain in the shared hosting

Tags: laravel-4, subdomain, shared-hosting

`Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/portalt/laravel/bootstrap/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src' (include_path='/home/portalt/laravel/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/portalt/laravel/bootstrap/start.php on line 59`

I got this error after hosting laravel 4 as sub-domain in the shared hosting. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an error with your vendors, have you run composer install?

Laravel on shared hosts can be problematic if you don't have ssh access, if you have ssh access make sure composer is installed:

```
composer --version
```

if it is then in your root directory run:

```
composer install
```

if it is not installed, download it from:
https://getcomposer.org/download/ and run install.

If you don't have ssh access have you been developing your application locally? you should be able to upload all your vendors via FTP.

How did you deploy your app and are the vendors in place?